# Django send API request best practice: inside model save or serializer?

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I have a model called `Customer`, and in the model save method, I send a request to the Stripe API to create a customer whenever a customer instance is created on my application. Another way I could do it is in the serializer.py file. That is, when a user creates a Customer instance on my application, it will automatically send a request to stripe to create a customer on that end. Which of these is the better practice? I believe, for "updating" customers, I will have to send the request to stripe from my serializers.py file. So might as well do the create customer from that file too. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your both approaches are correct either request Stripe in save method or after user creates a customer. And you don't need serializers for updating customers. Simply you can do this, just an example for updating card.

```
def update_card(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    """
        replace old card with new
    """

        customer = Customer.objects.get(user=request.user).stripe_cust_id
        # Customer is my custom table that recored stripe customer information

        stripe.Customer.modify(
            customer,
            source=request.POST['stripeToken'],
        )
```

my template

```
 <form action="{% url 'subscriptions:update_card' %}" method="post" id="payment-form">{% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="card-input-wrap m-4">

                                    <label for="card-element">Credit or debit card</label>
                                    <div id="card-element">
                                        <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Used to display form errors -->
                                    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>


                            </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ml-4 mb-4">Save Info <i class="la la-save"></i></button>
   </form>
```